# Overriding save method issues

Tags: django, overriding

I'm trying to override default save method according to [this article](http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2010/12/django-override-save-method-two-ways.html), but in both ways I'm getting following error:

- while using: `super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`, I'm getting: `name 'Blog' is not defined`
- while using: `models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)`, I'm getting: `name 'self' is not defined`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/7iyLybKf) is whole class - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First approach, are you importing Blog? or if it is defined in the same file, is it defined above? I saw the code of Exc. What does it has to do with Blog?

Comment: You do not provide all the code that would be necessary to help you.

Comment: I'm importing Exc - Blog is class from linked article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The call to the superclass's `save` method should happen in the class's `save` method (that line is not indented properly, so it's not within the `save` method.
2. You should call `super` with the current class, so `super(Exc, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.